# Cambiar la ruta de creacion de un excel con librería SpreadsheetLight

Tags: c#, visual-studio, excel, rutas, simplexlsx

Buenos días soy nueva en esto y estoy de prácticas,
trabajo con Visual Studio y tengo que crear un excel personalizandole.

Intento de miles de maneras poner la ruta donde quiero que se cree, pero solo se crea en la carpera debug.

Gracias de antemano.

Esto es el codigo que me funciona, pero lo agrga a Debug:

```
string pathFile = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + fileName + ".xlsx";
 
sl.SaveAs(pathFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado:

```
 string pathFile = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "/INFORMES LONJA/" + fileName + ".xlsx";

sl.SaveAs(pathFile);
```